# list-style outside isn't displayed but inside is

Tags: css, html-lists, invisible

The black discs before content inside the "li" are visible with this css: 
`li{ list-style: disc inside none; }`
But they don't show up with this code: 
`li{ list-style: disc outside none; }`
How can I make them visible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the padding-left attribute of the parent "ul" to something like: "20px", and they will show up.

Comment: Are you kidding me ?! Stackoverflow offers this "Q&A" feature. I just came across this problem and couldn't find a post for it. So thank you veery much for downvoting a correct answer. ...PS: Click on  "Ask Question" and you'll see "Answer your own question" at the bottom.

Comment: @Andri If you think it's a unique question & there's no answer in the stackoverflow. So, you have to mention this in your question. In your question you asked "How can I make them visible ?
". You are not waiting anyone for the answering your question.

Comment: @sandeep - It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. In fact, this is a new capability when asking questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Answer (score 1):

If **padding-left** not works then use margin-left to the main element for ex. in ul, then the li would get this disc outside perfectly.

Comment: Please don't post unsolicited links to your channel. If you do that, it can be considered spam on the site.